# How to set emacs as the default file manager?

Tags: dired, linux, integration

Some programs like firefox have buttons that when clicked open a file manager for browsing files. How do I make it to open in emacs with dired mode on Debian Linux?

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: I am using debian jessie.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Dependent on your desktop environment the method to set a default application may differ.  That said, many desktop environments respect the associations in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`, where you can set up an association for the `application/x-directory` and/or `inode/directory` types.

My `mimeapps.list` looks like this now:

```
[Default Applications]
application/x-directory=emacs-dired.desktop
inode/directory=emacs-dired.desktop
```

In the same directory I have a file called `emacs-dired.desktop` with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
NoDisplay=true
Exec=emacsclient --eval '(dired "%f")'
Name=Dired
Comment=Emacs Dired
```

When my long-lived instance of Emacs runs a server (`M-x server-start`) and I click on, say, the folder icon in the list of Downloads in Icecat a new `dired` buffer is opened.

This actually works for me now.  Thanks for asking the question --- otherwise I would not have set this up.

Answer (score 7):

This is how to make emacs as default file manager in ubuntu.

First we have to write a script which will act as our file manager.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        dirname =  sys.argv[1]
    else:
        dirname = '~'
    os.system('emacs --eval \'(dired "{}")\'%'.format(dirname))
    # you can use emacsclient if you are running emacs server

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Save this as `emacsfm` in `/usr/bin/`. Now in terminal instead of using `nautilus` or `nautilus /foo/bar`, we can use `emacsfm`  or `emacsfm /foo/bar`.

Now we need to set this as default file manager. Install `exo-utils` using

```
sudo apt-get install exo-utils
```

and run it

```
exo-preferred-applications
```

It opens a new window. Go to **Utilities** -> **File manager** -> **Other** and enter **/usr/bin/emacsfm "%s"** in  it.

You can goto chrome downloads and if click `show in folder` it will open emacs dired :-)

**Update:**

[image]
Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager

Comment: Anand, it works.. but it opens a new emacs window everytime.. it is good to use emacsclient that will open a new buffer in an already open emacs session....

Comment: i think, the previous answer addresses this point...

Comment: It does not work for me. Chrome still opens the folder in the application "Files" whereas firefox does not open anything and returns the following error: `Failed to query file manager via OpenDirectory: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method 'OpenDirectory'`

Answer (score 4):

Although the question is specifically for Linux I went and figured it out for Windows (since this prompted me to find how to do it for myself).

Interestingly enough, you don't have to invoke Dired, simply pass a folder as the file.  This saves a lot of hassle on Windows since `%1` will pass `c:\Users` (for example) and break on `\U` if included in the `eval` statement, while passing it as a file will properly parse it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell]
@="Dired"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\Dired]
@="Open in Dired"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\Dired\command]
@="\"%path/to/emacsclientw%\" %1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell]
@="XYplorer"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Dired]
@="Open in XYplorer"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Dired\command]
@="\"%path/to/emacsclientw%\" %1"
```

Reference: [Seven Forums - How to change the default File Manager](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/152674-how-change-default-file-manager.html)

Answer (score -4):

You can use Ranger. However you can configure xmonad for use emacs a windows default when you start session

Comment: Please expand on your answer to make it self-contained.